# How can I use group membership to restrict results?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In an MVC application, for a given action that all users are authorized to perform, I would like to filter results based on the user's group membership. For instance ...

- Users in GroupA should only see records pertaining to BuildingX.
- Users in GroupB should only see records pertaining to BuildingY.
- Users in GroupC should see all records.

I have no problem using authorization filters to restrict access to Actions, but I'm having a much harder time finding how to restrict access to *data* short of explicitly modifying statements every place where data is fetched.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A year later, working on a [different but related issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46916782/how-can-i-easily-filter-an-ef-dbset-most-of-the-time), I found the [EntityFramework.DynamicFilters](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework.DynamicFilters) package which does exactly what I need!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your records are in a database, the roles membership model doesn't extend to the database out of the box.  You can build a roles-based access control for your database, but you will likely save time using a simpler approach.  For example, using code like this in your controller:

```
if (Roles.IsUserInRole("GroupA")) {
 // Get data for GroupA.
}

// Display data...
```