# How can I easily filter an EF DbSet most of the time?

Tags: entity-framework, filtering

I have a collection of `Buildings` in my database. Up to this point, all buildings I've needed to track have been active, so to speak. A need has now arisen, though, to include a building that has been demolished and no longer exists. It seems fairly sensible to add a nullable DateTime property called `Decommissioned` to the `Building` class to track when a building has been taken offline.

The vast majority of my application fetches buildings by simply getting the entire set of all buildings from the DbContext. It would be a pain to add an additional `dbcontext.Buildings.Where(b => b.Decommissioned == null)` check to every instance, so filtering at the IDbSet level would be nice, but I still need these decommissioned buildings to show up in some contexts, like pulling up a resident's history of tenancies.

The question largely boils down to, how can I have the default behavior of `dbContext.Buildings` be to get me only non-decommissioned buildings, but still ask the DB in a special way to specifically *include* decommissioned buildings when I do want them?

Comment: See https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2014/05/29/missing-ef-feature-workarounds-filters/

Comment: You could also look at interceptors ala soft delete http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/soft-deleting-entities-cleanly-using-entity-framework-6-interceptors.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several days of exploring possible solutions that I couldn't quite get to do what I wanted, I ultimately found the [EntityFramework.DynamicFilters package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework.DynamicFilters) that did exactly what I needed and has in fact opened up the door to a bunch of new possibilities.